# Removing from the end of the file until you see a number or letter with sed/awk

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file ending with a number, character or a comma:

```
file1.txt
1 101 111 BCX A@WWW 123
1 101 111 BCX A@WWW 123;;;;;;
1 298 306 CCC A@QQQ 234-ck
1 298 306 CCC A@QQQ 234-ck;
1 298 306 CCC A@QQQ 234-ck ;;
1 299 308 CCD A@QQQ 234-cJ
1 299 309 DDD A@ZZZ 345;678
1 299 309 DDD A@ZZZ 345;678
```

The output should be :

```
    1 101 111 BCX A@WWW 123
    1 101 111 BCX A@WWW 123
    1 298 306 CCC A@QQQ 234-ck
    1 298 306 CCC A@QQQ 234-ck
    1 298 306 CCC A@QQQ 234-ck 
    1 299 308 CCD A@QQQ 234-cJ
    1 299 309 DDD A@ZZZ 345;678
    1 299 309 DDD A@ZZZ 345;678
```

What I do only removes one comma from the end:

```
cat file1.txt | sed 's/;$//g'

1 101 111 BCX A@WWW 123
1 101 111 BCX A@WWW 123;;;;;
1 298 306 CCC A@QQQ 234-ck
1 298 306 CCC A@QQQ 234-ck
1 298 306 CCC A@QQQ 234-ck ;
1 299 308 CCD A@QQQ 234-cJ
1 299 309 DDD A@ZZZ 345;678
1 299 309 DDD A@ZZZ 345;678
```

How can I remove all of the ";"s from the end of the file until I see a letter/number?

Comment: `sed 's/;*$//g'`

Comment: add a quantifier to `;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your sed, no need of cat

```
sed 's/;*$//' infile
```

using awk

```
awk '{sub(/;*$/,"")}1' infile
```